# Is it possible to search multiple Mongoose models at once?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have four Mongoose models, `SoleTrader`, `Partnership`, `Company` and `Trust`. They’re different enough that I can’t merge them all into one schema, yet similar enough that I regularly need to query or make changes to all 4 types at once and rarely care which sort they are.

Is there a way of doing this – possibly by putting all four types in a single collection – without making four database calls each time?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228882/inheritance-in-mongoose). The there mentioned [mongoose-schema-extend](https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend) sounds useful.

Comment: I'm already using mongoose-schema-extend to create the schemas, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't offer anything that would help with this problem. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: this article may help you https://dev.to/helenasometimes/getting-started-with-mongoose-discriminators-in-expressjs--22m9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using [`mongoose-schema-extend`](https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend), it seem like you could create a simple 'base' schema and extend your other schema's off that. If you want to search across all of them, use the base model.

For instance:

```
// base schema
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
  name : String
}, { 
  collection       : 'users', // everything will get saved in the same collection
  discriminatorKey : '_type' 
});

// two schema's that extend off it
var EmployeeSchema = PersonSchema.extend({ department : String });
var EmployerSchema = PersonSchema.extend({});

// materialize all three into models
var Person    = mongoose.model('Person',   PersonSchema);
var Employee  = mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema);
var Employer  = mongoose.model('Employer', EmployerSchema);

...

// create some people
new Employee({
  name       : 'Homer Simpson',
  department : 'Safety'
}).save(...);

new Employer({
  name : 'Charles Montgomery Burns',
}).save(...);

...

// search across employers and employees
Person.find({ ... }, function(err, people) {
  ...
});
```

However, I have to say that the [advertised behaviour](https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend#discriminator-key) of `find()` returning the correct model instance according to the discriminator key doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks, that works. The idea of saving the base schema as a model never even occurred to me; I had only been saving its extensions. I’ve been having the same problem with the discriminator key though. It’s not being saved at all.

Comment: @cbnz the key is saved to the db in my case, but it's not being used to 'cast' the results to the correct model. I'll file a bug report :)