# mongoose inheritance of statics methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, inheritance, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose in a Node.js application and I want to use inheritance of model. I'm following the instructions given here [Inheritance in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228882/inheritance-in-mongoose) and other links but I can't figure out how to make inheritance of statics methods.

Here is what I try :

```
// The BaseSchema class :
function BaseSchema(objectName, schema) {
    log.trace('BaseSchema CTOR : objectName=%s schema=%s', objectName, schema);
    Schema.apply(this, [schema]);

    var _objectName = objectName;
...
}
BaseSchema.prototype = new Schema();
BaseSchema.prototype.constructor = BaseSchema;

// !!! Here I try to expose the removeAll statics methods for all sub-schema !!!
BaseSchema.prototype.removeAll = function() { ... }
```

Here is the inherited class

```
// The inherited class
var AccountSchema = new BaseSchema('account', {
...
}
mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
```

The pb is that each time I try to utilize the removeAll function. For example :

```
var Account = mongoose.model('Account');
Account.removeAll(function () {
            done();
        });
```

I get this error message :

```
TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model))
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  } has no method 'removeAll'
```

I try different combinaison for declaring the removeAll methods without success :

```
BaseSchema.prototype.statics.removeAll = function() { ... }
BaseSchema.statics.removeAll = function() { ... }
```

Thank's in advance for your help !

JM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue yesterday, ended up doing something like this:

```
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;

function AbstractSchema() {
    Schema.apply(this, arguments);

    this.add({
        name: String,
        // ...your fields
    });

    this.statics.removeAll = function(){
        this.remove({}).exec();
        // ... your functionality
    };
}
```

Then just create your models;`mongoose.model('MyModel', new AbstractSchema())` and `MyModel.removeAll();` should work!

Comment: Thank's for your answer. It works great ! Just a limitation : in that case you create a new function for each instance and not a function attached to the class. I don't understand why the prototype method doesn't work. With the prototype method you have only one code (and it's better for test coverage for example).

Comment: I will post another question for istanbul test coverage not accurate with this method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904568/instanbul-cover-report-is-wrong-for-test-with-mocha-using-mongoose . Many Thank's for ypu solution !!

Comment: I know it's not the best solution, but I'm glad it helped you out!

Comment: @Nick, What does 'this' refers to?? -- 
I GET: "TypeError: Object #<AbstractSchema> has no method 'add'", if I comment it out I get -  
"OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Sample` model once compiled", did I miss something?

Comment: please explain what arguments is inside of the answer. Otherwise it doesn't make much sense, where is the this.add method used? Very incomplete answer, hope to see an update